# How can I send an audio reference to a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, audio, reference

I have an audio reference:

```
    const sound1 = useRef();
```

as I made it by:

```
   <audio  ref={sound1} src='/resources/DRUMS.mp3' loop={looping}></audio>
```

and a function I wnat to send it to:

```
const toggleMuteUnmute=(soundRef, isPlaying, stateFunc)=>{
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    stateFunc(!prevValue);
    if(prevValue){
        soundRef.current.muted = false;
        animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    }
    else{
        soundRef.current.muted = true;
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
    }
}
```

using this:

```
<button onClick={toggleMuteUnmute(sound1, isPlaying1, setIsPlaying1)} >
```

but an error comes up:

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'muted')

reffering to the first line in the 'else' statement.

Why can't it read the muted attribute of the html audio tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.
All I had to do was to put - `() =>` before the function call, as in -

```
<button onClick={() => toggleMuteUnmute(sound1, isPlaying1, setIsPlaying1)} >
```